# PHP PostgreSQL pg_exec doesn't work

Tags: php, postgresql

Hey, 
can someone tell me why my php doesen't execute the SQL Code in PGSQL.. The connection is working fine, i send query's with p_send_query but pg_execute doesen't work ..

```
   pg_send_query($PG_Con, 
      "INSERT into 'frontend_usermessage' 
              (opened, created, text, to_user_id, 
               from_user_id, administrative, subject) 
       VALUES ('NULL','$created','$text','$to_user',
               '$cookie','$admin','$fromuserr')") 
       or die(pg_error());

    $credits_new = $credits - 1;
    pg_send_query($PG_Con, "UPDATE users_mfuser SET song_credits='$credits_new' 
                     WHERE user_ptr_id='$cookie'") or die(pg_error());
```

Comment: People are really not interested in asking question they are just interested in posting questions

Comment: Where are you calling `pg_execute`? What doesn't work, are you getting errors? If so, please post them.

Comment: This is the problem, i try with pg_execute, pg_exec, pg_send_exec .. but nothing from this tree doesen't work.. Php don't send the information to PSQL with this tree commands. How to fix this functions ..

Answer (score 1):

U can use in this way for executing pg_execute(),

```
$Query = pg_query("your query here....").
pg_execute($Query);
```

it will work definitely..... and also please post your entire code so that i can explain you clearly..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but I see two problems int the SQL that you use

- The syntax `INSERT INTO 'frontend_usermessage'` is wrong. A table name may not be enclosed in single quotes
- `'NULL'` will insert the character string *NULL* into that column, **no**t a `NULL` value. If *opened* is not a varchar/text column, this will throw an error (unless there is some magic processing going on in PHP, that turns the string 'NULL' into a null value)

But you need to explain precisely what *doesen't work* means. 
*doesen't work* is not a valid Postgres error (and most probably not a valid PHP error either)